# Firebase signOut not performing as expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with my iOS app that uses firebase. I am signing out with the following code:

```
     @IBAction func logoutDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
            try! FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
```

although the app UI reflects a signOut, I am getting the following console message: 
 [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] Listener at /media failed: permission_denied
also, when I sign in with different user credentials, the app will be signed in as the old user.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {        

    //user logged in?
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {    //signed in
            DatabaseReference.users(uid: user.uid).reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    self.currentUser = User(dictionary: userDict)
                }
            })
        }else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.showWelcome, sender: nil)
        }
    })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: More than likely there's a condition where the sign out is pushed onto the stack and popped off before other listeners; therefore the app is trying to read a Firebase node after sign out; hence the permission denied. This could be a situation where you have a top-level observer and other events are happening within that closure, including the sign out function.

Comment: You need to go back to your older questions and mark answers correct or give feedback. It is bad form just to ask questions and not provide feedback to the people giving you answers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps but what i did is i add the addStateDidChangeListener in AppDelegate to check whether the current user is logged in or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()
    handle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil{
           // go to main screen if there is a user logged in

        }else{

           //go to login screen

        }

    })


    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this code into AppDelegate under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It skips a viewcontroller if the user is logged in.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

// MARK: Skip splash screen and login, if user is logged in
        storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        if currentUser != currentUser
        {
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        }
        else
        {
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        }
        return true
}
```